# WTForms syntax when using Flask and Flask-MongoAlchemy

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, wtforms

I am testing out Python framework Flask and **Flask-MongoAlchemy** with MongoDB (of course). As I'm building multiple documents in my test app, I like to get the forms validated us **WTForms**.

Can anyone share with me an example on how to create the object references in a SelectField()?

```
class Parent(db.Document):
    title = db.StringField()
    description = db.StringField()

class Object(db.Document):
    parent = db.DocumentField(Parent)
    title = db.StringField()

@app.route('/object/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_object():
    form = ObjectForm(obj=Object)
    form.parent.choices = [(???) for p in Parent.query.all()]  #<-- #1 correct syntax I like to understand, '(t._id, t.title)' didn't work.
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.save()
        return redirect(url_for('...'))
    return ....

class ObjectForm(wtf.Form):
    parent = wtf.SelectField(u'Parent')  #<-- #2 do I need to add anything special?
```

Any suggestion would be great!  Or link to an online example.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's documented in [WTForms documentation of the SelectField](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.2/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField) quoted here for convenience:

> Select fields keep a choices property which is a sequence of (value,
>   label) pairs.

I'm not sure about `form.parent.choices` syntax but the code looks like:

```
form.parent.choices = [(1, 'parent name 1'), (2, 'parent name 2'), (3, 'parent name 3'), (4, 'parent name 4')]
```

Comment: The parent table is going to have 100+ items in my case.  Examples online so far are only for sqlalchemy / most popular SQL DB, but not for mongoDB.  If you find anything, do let me know.  I'll keep searching.